# How do I update 0.0.0.0:5000 to show changes in app.py on foreman, ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, heroku, localhost, foreman

So I'm learning the ropes with `heroku` dev on `ubuntu` and I've run into something that was completely automatic for me while working with PHP.

How do you refresh the localhost to see the updates you did to the file, namely `app.py`?

Here is the app code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Once I launch the foreman using `$ foreman start`, it all runs; however, once I make some changes, for example adding some random letters to the return string, the thing I see after a refresh at `0.0.0.0:5000` is the same I had after starting the foreman.

How can I start seeing the changes I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [quickstart quide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/).  You need to run the server in debug mode to monitor for file changes.  Like so:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you set that as a config var in `.env`?